# System.InvalidOperationException: Page must not already have a parent

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, master-detail

In my Xamarin.Forms app I have this code:

```
while (this.Navigation.ModalStack.Count > 0)
{
    await this.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}

await Navigation.PushModalAsync(App.MyMasterDetailPage.Value);
```

On the last line, I get the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Page must not already have a parent.

How is it possible that `MyMasterDetailPage` has a parent when I've already popped everything off the `ModalStack` ? I only push it on the `ModalStack`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A MasterDetailPage is designed to be a root page, and using it as a
>   child page in other page types could result in unexpected and
>   inconsistent behavior. In addition, it's recommended that the master
>   page of a MasterDetailPage should always be a ContentPage instance,
>   and that the detail page should only be populated with TabbedPage,
>   NavigationPage, and ContentPage instances. This will help to ensure a
>   consistent user experience across all platforms.

Source: [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page)